In titanoboa, how do you set a private key / account?
I want to run this:
my_account: Account = Account.from_key(ANVIL_DEFAULT_KEY)
boa.add_account(my_account)
boa.set_network_env("URL_HERE")

So I can run the following:
counter: VyperDeployer = Counter.deploy()

How do I do this?

You need to set the network env first, before you add accounts.
boa.set_network_env("URL_HERE")
my_account: Account = Account.from_key(ANVIL_DEFAULT_KEY)
boa.add_account(my_account)

